# how to substitute machine numbers into an equation

Tags: replacement

I have a system of equations in which variables are indexed as:

```
8 x[1] + 2 y[1] == 2;
3 x[1] - 5 y[1] == 7;
```

The solution obtained **from my model** is of the form:

```
sol = {{x[1.] -> 12/23, y[1.] -> -(25/23)}};
```

As seen, the variable index looks like a `Machine Number` (x[1.] and y[1.]). Therefore, I cannot map the `sol` onto the equations to check if they are satisfied.

I simply want the `sol` to be:

```
{{x[1] -> 12/23, y[1] -> -(25/23)}};
```

How can I get rid of the `Machine Numbers` to be the variable index?

Comment: How are you solving the equations? If I simply write `Solve[{8 x[1] + 2 y[1] == 2, 3 x[1] - 5 y[1] == 7}]` I get `{{x[1] -> 12/23, y[1] -> -25/23}}` with no machine-precision numbers involved.

Comment: @eyorble: You are right. I also get the same thing as you. But in my model (bold text in my message) the solution is produced by using `x[1.], y[1.]` etc. That is why I indicated that this solution is specific to my model. I solve the model by `FindRoot[CGEmodel /. Flatten[{greekParamAssign, smallParamAssign}], 
   initialValues, AccuracyGoal -> 3, PrecisionGoal -> 30] // N;`

Comment: You can do `sol /. {x[n_] :> x[Rationalize[n]], y[n_] :> y[Rationalize[n]]}`.

Comment: @Marius Ladegard Meyer: I have about 1000 variables to rationalize. Is there a way to make the substitution you proposed easily?

Comment: If you have a 1000 variables, then surely they don't all have different `Head`s, right? Can you give an example of an actual variable name?

Comment: @Marius:  Here are some variable names used in the model: `
 QX[17.] , QXAC[1., 1.], EXR[1.], PA[2.], QA[3.], etc`. The heads are different for different variables.

Comment: Ok, assuming no other head-argument combinations appear that should not be tampered with, try `sol /. head_[n_] :> head[Rationalize[n]]`.

Comment: @Marius: I tried `sol /. head_[n_] :> head[Rationalize[n]]`. It works for those variables with one index value such as `PA[1.]` but it does not work for the variables with two index values such as `QXAC[1.,5.]`.

Comment: Please show some effort on your own here, the matter is just to deal with a `Sequence` of arguments (`n__`) instead of a single one. You have not mentioned any of these details in your question about 1000 variables and several indices.

Comment: @Marius: Thanks for your help. I will try to solve it on my own. Regards.

Comment: Following @Marius, would sol /. x_Symbol[y_Real] :> x[Round[y]] help you?

Comment: @Fred Simons: No, it did not help. I am still struggling with it. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Fred Simons: Mariu's suggestion worked for a variable with one index such as `X[1.]` but it did not work for variables with two indices such as `Y[2.,4.]` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one or more indices on different variable names, the following should work:

```
sol /. x_[n__?NumericQ] ->  :> x @@ Rationalize[{n}]
```

Of course, one can just `Rationalize` the whole thing, but that changes stuff on the RHS too, not only the indices.

A way of avoiding this problem all together is to **not** apply `N` to a whole expression containing variables indexed by numbers in the first place, but instead apply `N` only to the numerical stuff.

Comment: First, I like to thank you for your code, which works as expected. Also, I will be careful about the use of `N`. My problem is solved...

Comment: Another trick you can use is `SetAttributes[x, NHoldAll]`. This will prevent `N` from affecting arguments of `x`. So for example, `N[x[1]]` will just return `x[1]`.